# Assign variable from hiera as username (with uid and gid) inside puppet class

Tags: puppet

Hello Community members,

We have a puppet file which has a main class like below:

```
class profile::Profname::application::classname {

  $appname_homedir          = hiera('appname::appname_homedir')
  $appname_installdir       = hiera('appname::appname_installdir')
  $java_optional_args      = "${java_keystore_args} ${java_proxy_args} ${java_timezone_args}"
..
..
  $user                    = hiera('appname::appname_user')
  $gid                     = hiera('appname::appname_user_gid')
  $uid                     = hiera('appname::appname_user_uid')


exec { "Many blocks":
    command => "commands",
    ..
  }

exec { "Many blocks":
    command => "commands",
    ..
  }

#  Install and configure app

  class { 'app':
    user             => hiera('classname::appname_user'),
    jvm_opts         => $java_optional_args,
    download_url     => "s3://${s3_bucket}/${APPDIR}/appname",
    dbserver         => hiera('appname::db-endpoint'),
    notify           => Exec["Change appname gid and uid"],
    require          => [ Class['java'], Exec['Create Homedir'], Exec['Create Appdir']],
  }

#other exec blocks

exec { "blocks"
..
..
}

}
```

Now I have two more variables in hiera those are: uid and gid for the appname_user.

How can I create the user "appname_user" in the inner class 'app'?

I was trying to refer **https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/4.10/quick_start_user_group.html** but not sure how can I do this inside the inner class. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I did another exec block of changing the uid and gid for the user later when user is created but that way does not seem to be working for some files already present. Though puppet execution is successful. Hence I want to create the user with uid, and gid at the time of creation.

Thanks and Regards,
Saha

Answer (score 0):

> How can I create the user "appname_user" in the inner class 'app'?

My best guess is that you mean within this construct:

> ```
>   class { 'app':
>     user             => hiera('classname::appname_user'),
>     jvm_opts         => $java_optional_args,
>     download_url     => "s3://${s3_bucket}/${APPDIR}/appname",
>     dbserver         => hiera('appname::db-endpoint'),
>     notify           => Exec["Change appname gid and uid"],
>     require          => [ Class['java'], Exec['Create Homedir'], Exec['Create Appdir']],
>   }
> ```

The answer to that is simple: you can't.  But there is a variety of related things you could do.

First things first: "inner class" is not a term used in Puppet.  There can be *nested* classes, but

1. that's not what you have presented, and
2. nesting classes is widely regarded as poor style.

What you have shown is a *declaration* of class `app` inside the *definition* of class `profile::Profname::application::classname`.  A class declaration, when evaluated, tells Puppet to include the designated class in the catalog then under construction, and it optionally binds values to some that class's parameters.  There must be a definition of the class elsewhere to tell Puppet what that means.  If you want it to declare a resource that it does not already declare, then it is the definition that must be modified.

You would typically manage a user by declaring a `User` resource (inside one class definition or another).  In your case, you could find the definition of class `app` and put it there, but you could also put it in your profile class, alongside the existing declaration of class `app`.  Which one would serve you best depends on what you're trying to accomplish.